# How do I serve fully cached full HTML on cloudfront

Tags: cache, performance, cdn

I am using cloud front but want it to serve not just images and CSS but full static HTML pages that are cached locally.  I am using wp super cache ... I assume it is caching the full HTML for posts and pages.

But I am thinking it would be better to have as much of the site in Cloudfront.

I am currently using origin pull, but again it looks like HTML pages as just cached locally.

My site doesn't change much it is mostly interviews updated every couple of weeks.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to focus on its WordPress-relevant nature? For example, it looks like you're really asking, **How do I serve static HTML cached by WP Super Cache on CloudFront?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can serve HTML through CloudFront as long as you don't mind every user getting the same content until the cache expires. It completely depends how your caches are being stored.

I can't imagine a CDN that would not support this. They might not advertise it since many web sites are dynamic and can't be cached, but if your site is basically static, then any CDN should work.

**Source:** www.cloudreviews.com/blog

Comment: There are some cdn that cache dynamic pages and can invalid cache in ms. Fastly does that cloudfront too just people mostly use it for static assets mostly because it's hard to setup.